# Exception Opening Socket kmongo and ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I recently started to learn ktor so that i can make my own api  , i set up my server and everything is okey but now i want to apply this logic of saving data into a db and then simply load data from db and send it over to my server

- This is how i'm doing it now

```
private fun insertDetails(user : ArrayList<userCredentials>){
     val client = KMongo.createClient()
     var database = client.getDatabase("test")
     var collection = database.getCollection<ArrayList<userCredentials>>()
     CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
         collection.insertOne(user)
     }
 }
```

*This is how i'm getting data from kmongo db

```
private suspend fun getData() : List<ArrayList<userCredentials>> {
    return KMongo.createClient().getDatabase("test")
        .getCollection<ArrayList<userCredentials>>()
        .find().toList()
}
```

- This is an exception

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

i would like to ask if i'm doing it the right way

This is my scheme for that : save data in db -> get data from db -> send it over to my server m thank you

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the mongo daemon is running and the target port is opened in firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to have mongo daemon running: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#using-mongodb-from-10gen-builds

What I had to do:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

And then it worked.